# ASP.NET MVC 5: Output Caching Child Action programmatically

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I need to force to output cache a specific child action on a user's login because I have to avoid caching this child action by a parent action which uses the `AuthorizeAttribute`.
However when calling the child action programmatically inside the Login action method to cache it, the caching doesn't work.

Child action call:

```
HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
var actionResult = homeController.MainMenu();
```

Child action:

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(Duration = 300, VaryByCustom = "User")]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult MainMenu()
{
    return PartialView("MainMenu");
}
```

**Addition:**

I am aware of the issue that this procedure contravenes against the concept of the caching process. However I need to do this because the login can redirect the user to its logout page where the child action can be called by a action which uses the `AuthorizeAttribute`. The child action is part of the layout page, therefore I need it to be prerendered/cached by action method which doesn't uses the  Authorize Attribute. This is because the `AuthorizeAttribute` doesn't support output caching of child actions.

Comment: What makes you think that output cache doesn't work if `Authorize` is in play?

Comment: @ChrisPratt When you look inside the code of the `AuthorizeAttribute` you can find [this comment](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L87-L90)

Comment: That's only a problem if the child action itself requires authorization, which you shouldn't be doing anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Child actions are the actions called inside views with Html.Action() helper.

You should call your child action inside your login view not inside your controllers action.

I believe output caching should work then.

You should read up on Donut and Donut Hole caching 
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/ODJa210113-Donut-Caching-and-Donut-Hole-Caching-with-Asp.Net-MVC-4.html

I believe that's what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: The problem is that the child action I need to get cached is not called by the login view, because the login view uses a different layout file.

Comment: I dont understand what you're trying to achieve, could post the rest of the parent action that you are calling your child action in?

Answer (score 0):

The output cache is handled by the request processing machinery. Calling the method directly doesn't activate any of that. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but it seems this is pointless anyways. The first time the child action is rendered, it will be cached for the user. Priming the cache on login only moves that few milliseconds of processing time from one request to the other. Either way, the user is subjected to the initial load of the child action, it's only a case of when. Given that, just let nature take its course, and let it happen when it should: the first time it's needed.

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify why in my case I need to do it. However you are of course right with your point.